# Tools to flash the firmware from terminal/gui

Tags: 11.10, firmware

What tools can I find in Ubuntu to flash the firmware of the motherboard or any other hardware from terminal or gui. Specially for those formats that ask for a 3.5 disk (In this time of age??) or other formats made that are troublesome to do.

Comment: Here's a guide http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318789

Comment: Wazzap Uri, can you make it into an Answer here in Askubuntu please.

Comment: Also a DOS emulator surely can do the trick for those old motherboards, for the new ones unless the OEM provides an alternative to windows based flashing tools you'll be out of luck.

Comment: sure can, but does it work for you?.

Comment: It's not something I will be testing right now, but I will come to this question to see the answers when I go to work tomorrow.

Comment: Almost a dupe here: http://askubuntu.com/q/25129/3940

Comment: @Takkat - In that question they were very specific about what bios update method and hardware model. In this case is generic. Also in that case the actual answer is not even in askubuntu. Am asking for it to be here to remove the need to look for it somewhere else.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado: that's exactly why I didn't cast any evil votes ;) We do need a question that covers general aspects.

Comment: +1 to that bro and also that the answers be here for faster search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a word of caution, if there is a problem updating your bios or if you make a mistake you might render you computer inoperable / unbootable. I highly advise you start by confirming with your vendor that a bios update is advisable.

Second, some vendors, such as Dell, offer Linux options.

http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/firmware

If your vendor only offers a .exe , if at all possible, I would run it from Windows.

There are 3 alternates available to you if you do not run windows:

1. [Biosdisk (Dell)](http://linux.dell.com/git/biosdisk.git)
2. [Flashrom](http://www.flashrom.org/Flashrom)
3. [Freedos](http://www.freedos.org/)

### Biosdisk

You will have to download and install biosdisk from [here](http://linux.dell.com/git/biosdisk.git)

You then extract the archive and install it

```
tar xvf biosdisk-git-06112010.tar.gz
cd biosdisk

sudo ./install.sh
```

You can then make a .deb with

```
biosdisk mkpkg /path/to/bios_update.exe
```

### Flashrom

Flashrom is in the ubuntu repositories and supported hardware is listed [here](http://www.flashrom.org/Supported_hardware)

```
sudo apt-get install flashrom
```

Make a backup of your current BIOS

```
sudo flashrom -r backup.bin
```

Install a new BIOS

```
sudo flashrom -w new_bios.bin
```

### FreeDOS

[Freedos](http://www.freedos.org/) can be installed to a flash drive with unetbootin. You then boot from the flash drive and use the DOS command line to run your bios .exe

The [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux) has a page with additional detail on all these tools.